# What is the purpose of concrete methods in abstract classes in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, oop, abstract-class

I feel like this subject is touched in some other questions but it doesn't get into Python (3.7) specifically, which is the language I'm most familiar with.

I'm starting to get the hang of abstract classes and how to use them as blueprints for subclasses I'm creating.

What I don't understand though, is the purpose of concrete methods in abstract classes.

If I'm never going to instantiate my parent abstract class, why would a concrete method be needed at all, shouldn't I just stick with abstract methods to guide the creation of my subclasses and explicit the expected behavior?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This question is not Python specific, but general object oriented.

There may be cases in which all your sub-classes need a certain method with a common behavior. It would be tedious to implement the same method in all your sub-classes. If you instead implement the method in the parent class, all your sub-classes inherit this method automatically. Even callers may call the method on your sub-class, although it is implemented in the parent class. This is one of the basic mechanics of class inheritance.

Comment: Then I suppose my question  is more along the lines of : 'what is the difference between abstract and concrete methods within abstract classes?" If one wants to enforce some behavior I don't see how they're different ?

Comment: Abstract methods need to be implemented before any sub-class can be instantiated. It’s like a contract declared in the abstract class: any instance of this class resp. its sub-classes will have these methods implemented.

Comment: The difference of abstract and concrete methods is that concrete methods are implemented whereas abstract methods are not. A class with abstract methods can not be instantiated.

Comment: We can do it, Python is allowing that, but is it a good practice to dump common methods to abstract classes in terms of OOP perspective?